# Two view App with root template view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator

Hi I was wanted to do Application witch have a root template view with a nice logo on top or something adn load other views just below

(here is what I have right now: [Test App](http://www.tieman.pl/smiecie/Test.zip)
)

But I have a little problem. If I'll remove a comment in file TestAppDelegate.m on line 58

```
    //[currentView release];
```

Application will crash with bunch of errors when I try to switch views.
But if I comment this line Project analyzer is telling me that I have a potential leak 
with **currentView** variable.

Can somebody spare some time and see in that code what I did wrong?

Comment: How you are creating *currentView*? Are you allocating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are only adding `currentView.view` as a subview so that is being retained elsewhere but `currentView` itself is not. This means that when you release it, it is consequently dealloc'd and its view will have difficulty working without it.

One solution would be to have `currentView` as an instance variable and create a property for it so that the memory mangement is done for you.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *currentView;
```

and then replace a line like

```
currentView = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:nil];
```

with

```
self.currentView = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:nil];
```

This will release the old view controller before retaining the new one. Then lastly don't forget to release `currentView` in the `dealloc` method of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function and it looks like this:

```
- (void) switchView: (int) viewType {

for (UIView *view in [self.viewController.rootView subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

UIViewController *currentView = nil;

switch (viewType) {
    case 1:
        currentView = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:nil];
        break;

    case 2:
        currentView = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
        break;

}

[self.viewController.rootView addSubview: [currentView view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//[currentView release];
```

}

Comment: Don't add this as answer. You can edit your question using the link at the bottom of your question..